# Replacing smileys in a string crashing the page

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace smileys in a string like below

```
    function decoder(text, done) {
        async.parallel([

        function (cback) {
            // Thanks to @CMS
            var emoticons = window.symbols,
                patterns = [],
                metachars = /[[\]{}()*+?.\\|^$\-,&#\s]/g;

            // build a regex pattern for each defined property
            for (var i in emoticons) {
                if (emoticons.hasOwnProperty(i)) { // escape metacharacters
                    patterns.push('(' + i.replace(metachars, "\\$&") + ')');
                }
            }

            // build the regular expression and replace
            text = text.replace(new RegExp(patterns.join('|'), 'g'), function (match) {
                return typeof emoticons[match] != 'undefined' ?
                    "<img src='/" + emoticons[key] + "' />" : match;
            });

            cback(null, true);
        },

        function (cback) {
            var ref = window.smileys,
                keys = Object.keys(ref);
            async.each(keys, function (key, cb) {
                text = text.replace(new RegExp('[' + key + ']', 'gi'), "<img src='/" + ref[key] + "' />");

                cb(null);
            }, function () {
                cback(null, true);
            });
        }], function (err, res) {
            done(text);
        });
    }
```

But this is making the page crashed. Is there any specific code blocking this issue, while debugging I have observed second function is blocking it but could not understand why. The total number of smileys are 300. And smileys are in the format of `[Dancing]`, `[Kidding]` and `:)` etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using regular expressions used below trick, this worked very well and thanks to @James McLaughlin

```
 text = text.split(smileySymbol).join(imgHTML);
```